# Is there a way to tell if a Jenkins server has finished shutting down?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, virtual-machine

I am running Jenkins on a virtual machine and calling the cli from a batch file to do a safe shutdown like so:

```
java -jar $JenkinsCLILocation -s http://$JenkinsURL safe-shutdown
```

Once it's finished shutting down, I'm turning off the virtual machine and cloning it.  However, I don't want to turn off the virtual machine before the safe shutdown of Jenkins is complete.  Is there any way I can monitor the Jenkins using either the cli or a batch command to see if it's properly shut down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most ghetto hack.  What I'm basically doing is looking at the error output from the java command that executes the Jenkins CLI jar file, and if the error output contains "Failed to connect", I assume that the Jenkins has been shut off.

I would love to see if anyone has a more graceful solution, cause man, this is just gross.

```
while(!$JenkinsIsDown)
{
    Write-Host "Getting the session ID from Jenkins to check if it's down..."

    #This is a terrible hack so we can process the output of the command
    $JenkinsProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $JenkinsProcess.FileName = "java"
    $JenkinsProcess.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $JenkinsProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $JenkinsProcess.UseShellExecute = $false
    $JenkinsProcess.Arguments = "-jar " + $JenkinsCLILocation + " -s http://" + $JenkinsURL + " session-id" 
    $JenkinsProcess.WaitForExit()
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $JenkinsProcess
    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    $p.WaitForExit()
    $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()        

    if($stderr.Contains("Failed to connect"))
    {
        Write-Host "The Jenkins is down."
        $JenkinsIsDown = $true
    }
}
```